# Relleno de forma en css

Tags: html, css

Tengo la siguente forma de "silo" formada por un CONO-CUERPO (Triangulo-Rectangulo) que necesito rellenar según el porcentaje que tenga 0%-50%-100% de su capacidad.

Pude dibujar las formas en css pero no logro rellenar el fondo con efecto de llenado.

```css
.cuadrado{
width: 0;
height: 0;
border-top: 130px solid black;
border-right: 50px solid black;
border-left: 50px solid black;
}
.triangulo{
width: 0;
height: 0;
border-top: 30px solid black;
border-right: 50px solid transparent;
border-left: 50px solid transparent;
}
#silo {
  max-width:100px;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}
#silo::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  background: #04ACFF;
  width: 100%;
  bottom: 0;
  animation: wipe 5s cubic-bezier(.2,.6,.8,.4) forwards;
}
@keyframes wipe {
  0% {
    height: 0;
  }
  60% {
    height: 60%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="silo">
  <div class="cuadrado"></div>
  <div class="triangulo"></div>
</div>
```

1 - ¿Existe otra forma mejor de dibujarlo para poder interactuar con variables y no modificar el CSS?

2 - ¿Las dos formas se pueden combinar en una sola?